# Python 3.11 with no builtin pip module - what's going on?

Tags: python, pip

```
.venv/bin/python -m pip uninstall mysqlclient
/Users/anentropic/dev/project/.venv/bin/python: No module named pip
```

and

```
.venv/bin/python
Python 3.11.5 (main, Sep 18 2023, 15:04:25) [Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

I thought `pip` was a builtin for recent Python versions, how is it that I have one where it doesn't exist?

Comment: Is your venv messed up? `python -m pip --version`  prints `pip 24.0 from /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip (python 3.12)` for me.

Comment: does `pip3` works?

Comment: @OmerDagry no, I was completely missing the pip tool and aliases etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...

`pip` isn't actually a "builtin" in recent Python versions

What changed is it began to be bundled with Python installs by default, so it's usually available

For whatever reason (perhaps because my venv was created by [pdm](https://pdm-project.org/)) mine did not come with it

This can be fixed by:

```
.venv/bin/python -m ensurepip
```

which installs it

After that `.venv/bin/python -m pip install` etc work ok